# MVC error when trying to use model in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, model

My problem occurs when I try to tell the view which model to use. It only happens with this model though.. Here is the model code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Com.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Components
    {

    }

    public class headerModel
    {
        public virtual String title { get; set; }
        public virtual String subtitle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the view when I try to add it like this

```
@model Com.Domain.Entities.headerModel;
```

It gives me this error:

> only assignment call increment decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement

I'm not sure what's going on. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to remove the `;` at the end of the model declaration?

Comment: Wow, it's clearly been a long day. Thank you though!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `;` at the end of the model declaration in your view

```
@model Com.Domain.Entities.headerModel
```